# ¿Para que sirve poner el tipo de variable en un método?

Tags: java

Es solamente una pequeña duda.
¿De que sirve declarar el tipo de variable antes de un método? Me refiero a algo así:

```
public int [][] ejemplo(){}
public double ejemplo(){}
public String toString(){}
```

Puede que ya lo supiera de antes, pero no logro recordarlo, apreciaría una explicación o una fuente de información.

Comment: Es el tipo de dato que retorna el método.

Comment: Oh, gracias @Lobos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recuerda que los métodos pueden **retornar valores** por lo que si tienes un método como el siguiente:

```
public double saldo(){}
```

Seguramente en su interior tendría un **return** devolviendo ese  valor:

```
public double saldo(){ return this.saldo;}
```

Se tienes un metodo que no retorna nada tendrías algo como lo siguiente:

```
public void nombreDeTuMetodo(){}
```